# scp between two remote machines needing password authentication

Tags: ssh, passwords, scp

#### Background

I want to copy files from a remote machine `remoteA` to another `remoteB`.
These machines require password authentication.

#### Steps I tried

I tried this command

```
$ scp -3 user@remoteA:/path/to/file user@remoteB:/path/to/dest
```

then double password prompt appeared in a line.

```
Password: Password:
```

then I entered passwords as follows,

```
Password:
Password:
Password:
Password:
user@remoteB: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
user@remoteA: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

but permission denied.

Is there any way to scp between these machines?

---

#### Environment

**local machine**

- macOS Mojave 10.14.4
- `ssh -V`: OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

---

#### Modified #1

I already have `.ssh/config` files as follows

```
Host remoteA
  HostKeyAlias remoteA
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/mux-%r@%h:%p
Host remoteB
  HostKeyAlias remoteB
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/mux-%r@%h:%p
```

Comment: Generate ssh key pair(s) and properly install them on remoteA, remoteB (public key) and the local machine (private key(s)). Then you don't need to enter passwords. If you can't do that, experiment with `ssh-askpass` and/or `ssh-agent`, so you can enter the passwords beforehand.

Comment: I had no previlege to change remote machines so I set `ssh-askpass` then made it. Thanks, @dirkt !

Comment: For the next person with the same problem, please write an answer providing details of what you did do. You can accept your own answer. (Also, if you can copy files to the remote machines, you can probably make a file `.ssh/authorized_keys`, either with `ssh` or `scp`, and this is all you need to set up keys on the remote machines, unless you have a non-default configuration on them).

Comment: `ssh-askpass` not work properly again. https://superuser.com/questions/1434275/scp-between-two-remote-machines-needing-password-authentication#comment2164627_1434275

Answer (score 3):

`ControlMaster` settings (as above **Modified #1** Section) skip asking password.

First, connect each server using `ssh` command.

```
(ttys001)
$ ssh remoteA
---
(ttys002)
$ ssh remoteB
```

Then, do `scp` in another tty.

```
(ttys003)
$ scp -3 user@remoteA:/path/to/file user@remoteB:/path/to/dest
```